# JSONDoc Annotation on multidimensional objects

Tags: java, json, api, documentation, jsondoc

I am trying to put annotations from JSONDoc on multidimensional objects but with no success.

Example:

```
@ApiObjectField(description = "Multidimensional array with flags")
private boolean[][] flags;
```

The following exception is raised:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appservlet] in context with path [/database] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name [Z] with root cause org. reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name [Z
at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:378)
at org.jsondoc.core.util.JSONDocUtils.getObjectNameFromAnnotatedClass(JSONDocUtils.java:125)
at org.jsondoc.core.pojo.ApiObjectFieldDoc.getFieldObject(ApiObjectFieldDoc.java:70)
...
```

Someone knows how to resolve this or know another library to generate JSON documentation that can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is using a class to enclose the multidimensional objects, like `List<List<Boolean>>`.